# How to take backup of package of Webrole in the new Azure Resource manager Fluent

Tags: azure-sdk-.net, azure-management-api

I need to take backup of web role package and store it in a azure storage
In the older version of I had use Azure Management Library
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Libraries/

```
            string deploymentName = computeClient.Deployments.GetBySlot(serviceName, DeploymentSlot.Production).Name;
            string label = computeClient.Deployments.GetBySlot(serviceName, DeploymentSlot.Production).Label;

            DeploymentGetPackageParameters packageParam = new DeploymentGetPackageParameters();

            Uri containerUri = new Uri(storageBackupURI);
            string containerName = containerUri.AbsolutePath.Remove(0, 1);

            packageParam.ContainerUri = containerUri;
            packageParam.OverwriteExisting = true;

            Console.WriteLine("Copying Package");
            OperationStatusResponse osr = computeClient.Deployments.GetPackageByName(serviceName, deploymentName, packageParam);
```

how would I accomplish using fluent api.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that currently [this Library v1.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent) supports major parts of Azure Virtual Machines, Virtual Machine Scale Sets, Managed Disks, Storage, Networking, Resource Manager, SQL Database, App Service, Key Vault, Redis, CDN and Batch etc. Cloud Services are not supported and this library will only support Azure Resource Manager Providers, you could find the below info from [this blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/simpler-azure-management-libraries-for-net/).

[image]

To manage Cloud Services, as you did in your earlier project, you could still use Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Libraries.

Besides, you will find “*Feature Availability and Road Map as of Version 1.0.0*” in [this article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/Fluent).